# Offline playback DRM-encrypted MPEG-DASH content with JWPlayer

Tags: jwplayer, offline, playback, drm, widevine

I'm working on an Android project where I need to play offline DRM-encrypted MPEG-DASH content with JWPlayer. DRM in used is Widevine. From different sources I e.g. this one: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/17033158-jwplayer-offline-playback they said it is not possible

> "If you could remove DRM as a requirement then that would indeed be a
>   viable solution for you."

However, what if we can preload the license & the persistent key? 
If we can override JWPlayer's method to provide required license and keys to JWPlayer, will it work?

Comment: In theory widevine itself takes care of the license persistence so if you are prepared to play around with the way JWPLayer requests the license then it should be possible make it work. I would look at Exoplayer as an example - the last post in this thread may be useful: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/949

Comment: Hello, did you get it to work? I tried Exoplayer, Bitmovin so far, but offline doesn't work.